# 'System.ArgumentException: boundary' When uploading files to Discord using Discord.net API

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, discord, discord.net

I am trying to send a local image to a Discord channel (though one of my servers) using the .net Discord API from a C# console program hosted on a raspberry pi 3 running raspbian lite.

However, in doing so, I am getting  `System.ArgumentException: boundary`:

```
Discord.Commands.CommandException: Error occurred executing "$phtake" for yangman#3640 in YANGNET/moderator-channel. ---> System.ArgumentException: boundary
  at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent..ctor (System.String subtype, System.String boundary) [0x00062] in <17d6c7facb7941c2ae864b4fe324e825>:0
  at System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent..ctor (System.String boundary) [0x00000] in <17d6c7facb7941c2ae864b4fe324e825>:0
  at Discord.Net.Rest.DefaultRestClient.SendAsync (System.String method, System.String endpoint, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] multipartParams, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancelToken, System.Boolean headerOnly, System.String reason) [0x0008d] in <384170f933f2420883fb2b21834d3dc7>:0
  at Discord.Net.Queue.MultipartRestRequest.SendAsync () [0x000a4] in <384170f933f2420883fb2b21834d3dc7>:0
  at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestBucket.SendAsync (Discord.Net.Queue.RestRequest request) [0x001b9] in <384170f933f2420883fb2b21834d3dc7>:0
  at Discord.Net.Queue.RequestQueue.SendAsync (Discord.Net.Queue.RestRequest request) [0x00108] in <384170f933f2420883fb2b21834d3dc7>:0
  at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendInternalAsync (System.String method, System.String endpoint, Discord.Net.Queue.RestRequest request) [0x000e0] in <384170f933f2420883fb2b21834d3dc7>:0
  at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.SendMultipartAsync[TResponse] (System.String method, System.String endpoint, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] multipartArgs, System.String bucketId, Discord.Net.Queue.ClientBucketType clientBucket, Discord.RequestOptions options) [0x000c9] in <384170f933f2420883fb2b21834d3dc7>:0
  at Discord.API.DiscordRestApiClient.UploadFileAsync (System.UInt64 channelId, Discord.API.Rest.UploadFileParams args, Discord.RequestOptions options) [0x001df] in <384170f933f2420883fb2b21834d3dc7>:0
  at Discord.Rest.ChannelHelper.SendFileAsync (Discord.IMessageChannel channel, Discord.Rest.BaseDiscordClient client, System.IO.Stream stream, System.String filename, System.String text, System.Boolean isTTS, Discord.Embed embed, Discord.RequestOptions options, System.Boolean isSpoiler) [0x000f7] in <384170f933f2420883fb2b21834d3dc7>:0
  at Discord.Rest.ChannelHelper.SendFileAsync (Discord.IMessageChannel channel, Discord.Rest.BaseDiscordClient client, System.String filePath, System.String text, System.Boolean isTTS, Discord.Embed embed, Discord.RequestOptions options, System.Boolean isSpoiler) [0x000b6] in <384170f933f2420883fb2b21834d3dc7>:0
  at Discord.WebSocket.SocketTextChannel.Discord.IMessageChannel.SendFileAsync (System.String filePath, System.String text, System.Boolean isTTS, Discord.Embed embed, Discord.RequestOptions options, System.Boolean isSpoiler) [0x00090] in <3331075733c74092b9fa467c888c9e7b>:0
  at DISCORDBOT.Modules.ExampleCommands.phTake () [0x0018c] in <f7377afb943742a18fbcc33b92191af1>:0
  at Discord.Commands.ModuleClassBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<BuildCommand>g__ExecuteCallback|0 (Discord.Commands.ICommandContext context, System.Object[] args, System.IServiceProvider services, Discord.Commands.CommandInfo cmd) [0x00151] in <daa3127b39d34db2bae7cf69a3b7da92>:0
  at Discord.Commands.CommandInfo.ExecuteInternalAsync (Discord.Commands.ICommandContext context, System.Object[] args, System.IServiceProvider services) [0x001ae] in <daa3127b39d34db2bae7cf69a3b7da92>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Such an error does not occur on my windows machine - which successfully sends the image - so I'm guessing it might be due to an outdated package of some sort, however, I think that's not the case.

**So why does this exception occur?**

Here's my simple method in sending the image:

```
        [Command("$phtake")]
        [RequireContext(ContextType.Guild)]
        public async Task phTake()
        {

            string path = $@"{Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())}/bin/image.jpg";
            Console.WriteLine(path);

            await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(path, "your image: ");

        }
```

I've tried different images on the raspberry pi, as to check whether the image was provoking this error, alas, it does not.

I have also noticed that embedding the image works using the discord.net `EmbedBuilder()`, however, it also provokes the error when embedding local files. It might be possible to host this file to a web service and somehow embed the image URL into the Embed Builder, but that would require the script to upload the file and retrieve it, which I am a novice at.
EDIT: using the `SendFileAsync()` function seem to provoke this error.

If anyone has ideas regarding possible ways to fix this issue or ideas regarding possible workarounds, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Embeds do support [local attachments](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.EmbedBuilder.html#usage-with-local-images)

Comment: @Anu6is yes, but the error seems to come from SendFileAsync() which supports local attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days I've developed a work around:

Instead of using the `SendFileAsync()` method I decided to embed the image using `EmbedBuilder()`

Because no instances of `SendFileAsync()` worked, I used the [Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/) to send and retrieve my image as a URL. By attaching this URL, I was able to send the same image.